# What's the best way to handle platform specific keys in Selenium/Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My problem is simple:

I want to do a "select all". This is done differently in macosx compared to linux and windows.

> Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a")

vs

> Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, I do little workaround for this:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
if (os.equals("WINDOWS")){
   Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
}else{
   Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a");
}
```

Basically - I get the OS where do I run and behave by that accordingly

Comment: Sure, but you were too quick! I had to wait 3 hours before I were allowed to accept an answer..and then it left my mind until now

Comment: This does not actually work on OS X.. seems like it does not support native key events. Ref: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3101

Comment: According to this LINUX will fail

Answer (score 5):

Since Linux and Windows both support CONTROL, then the only difference would be MAC (Darwin), so I would rather use:

**Python:**

```
import platform

os_base = platform.system()

If os_base == 'Darwin':

    selector.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'a')

else:

    selector.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
```

Comment: This does not work. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/622